# Persistent Objects in Wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, caching, object-persistence

I would like to create a set of persistent objects that load their state from the database and are then persisted in memory for Wordpress/PHP page loads to use as cached memory objects. I would imagine an interface for these objects to include:

- initialise() - load state from database and perform any other initialisation functions needed prior to servicing requests
- getter_foo() - a series of getter methods for PHP code to call for memory cached responses
- getter_bar() - a series of getter methods for PHP code to call for memory cached responses
- update() - called by time or event driven processes that ask the object to go back to the database and refresh its state

The two tricks I suspect are:

1. Have the main PHP process alloc and hold the memory reference for these objects so that they remain pinned to memory across web transactions/requests without needing to reinitialise each time against the database
2. Having a mechanism to allow the transactional processes to gain a pointer to this objects.

Are there any examples of solutions that do this? I've been programming for years but am very new to both Wordpress and PHP so maybe this is quite straight forward. Not sure. In any event, I do recognise that technical solutions like *redis* and *memcached* might achieve similar goals but in a less elegant and non-contextual way. That said, if there's no easy way to do this I'm happy to use the 80/20 rule. :^)

Comment: Have you looked into serialize? http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php it's generally a good way to keep object state between requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to store data in memory during 1 request, and then read it back from memory during another request using nothing but plain PHP. Sure the PHP process uses memory, but as soon as your request is finished, that part of the memory gets garbage collected. Which means that a second request cannot access that previous part of the memory again.

What you are hinting at, is called caching. Simply put, caching means that you save the output of an expensive transaction for later re-use, to save on the cost of that transaction. What you then use as a backend to store that output is up to you or what you have available. If you want to save it to the RAM, then you would need something like Memcached. You could also store it in regular file, but that is slower because of the hard drive being accessed.

Comment: Thanks Miljar. I'm aware of memcached and redis. I will probably use them but was hoping for a mechanism like I described as there can be some nice benefits to it over more infrastructural solutions like memcached/redis.

Comment: I guess if you're right that there's no way to do this then that also means there's no way to build a database management layer that keeps a pool of open connections to the database. Unless maybe Wordpress is smart enough to do this itself? On high transaction sites this is a big benefit as you're able to maintain connections and get more reuse out of bind variables too.

Comment: It's possible to keep an open connection shared in one request. But I've never heard of sharing it across multiple requests. If you have so many reads from your DB, I would try to cache the results of your query to memcache, and consider a Master-Slave setup for your database with a pool of slave's to read from.

Comment: I think you're probably right Miljar. In some of the really big apps I've been involved in through the years the pool connections sharing was of big value but this was all in a pre-memcached era.

Comment: The benefits were two fold: (1) The cost of openning and closing connections between the business logic and data storage tiers was expensive and (2) the database had to run an explain on similarly structured queries rather than use bind variables to avoid this overhead. I suspect with memcached you are achieving an 80/20 rule with very little effort so there are fewer cases where expending the effort in the last 20% of the continuum makes sense. I'll close this question for now. Thanks for your input.